# What is the best way to calculate number of padding bytes

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, padding

What's the most efficient way to calculate the amount of padding for 8-bit data that needs to be a multiple of 32-bit in C?

At the moment I do it like this:

```
pad = (4-size%4)%4;
```

Comment: For powers of two, you can use `&` instead of `%`:  `pad= (4 - ( 0x3 & size )) & 0x3 ;`

Comment: @woolstar the compiler will produce the exact same code, I believe. It's just that yours is less readable.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? What don't you like about that code?

Comment: I believe your current version is the best possible if you don't want to introduce undefined behavior

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer, because it's technically UB in C/C++ (and not very readable), but... `(4-size)&3`

Comment: `-size&3` should be the same.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson still UB, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't doubt that there's something I missed (again), but why UB in this case? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson bitwise operations on negative numbers are UB, IIRC

Comment: In practice you won't meet anything but a two's complement, but the compiler might still freak out on higher optimisation levels.

Comment: Why are you padding btw?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Bitwise operations on integers, whether negative are not, are defined. The **bitwise** result is completely defined; the **mathematical** result depends on the representation, which, for signed integers, is constrained by C 2011 6.2.6.2 2 to be one of sign and magnitude, two’s complement, or one’s complement, possibly with padding bits. In general, this can result in a trap value, but the `&3` operation in particular cannot yield a trap value since it clears the high bit.

Comment: Why bother with signed arithmetic, size is presumably unsigned no? so (-size)&0x3 is perfectly valid.

Comment: @aka.nice `(-size)` is an overflow in unsigned arithmetic. Thus, UB.

Comment: @JanDvorak Huh? isn't unsigned overflow a well defined (modular) behavior?

Comment: @JanDvorak `unsigned size; (-size)` is well defined.  "A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow..."  C11dr §6.2.5 9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the optimizing compiler uses bitmasking for the `% 4` instead of division, I think your code is probably pretty good. This might be a slight improvement:

```
// only the last 2 bits (hence & 3) matter
pad = (4 - (size & 3)) & 3;
```

But again, the optimizing compiler is probably smart enough to be reducing your code to this anyway. I can't think of anything better.

Comment: I have been staring at both the question and the answer for a while now but I just cannot see why the outer "& 3" is necessary. Help? Edit: Never mind I saw it. It's necessary when "size & 3 == 0" because we rather pad 0 than pad 4.

Comment: Info for others: This approach only works for powers of 2.

Answer (score 5):

```
// align n bytes on size boundary
pad n size = (~n + 1) & (size - 1)
```

this is similar to TypeIA's solution and only machine language ops are used.

```
(~n + 1) computes the negative value, that would make up 0 when added to n
& (size - 1) filters only the last relevant bits.
```

examples

```
pad 13 8 = 3
pad 11 4 = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`pad = (-size)&3;`

This should be the fastest.

```
size 0: pad 0
size 1: pad 3
size 2: pad 2
size 3: pad 1
```

Comment: Though it assumes two's complement if `size` is of signed type, perhaps better to cast `size` explicitly to `size_t`

Comment: Elegant, but it only works if you want to pad by some power of 2. In my case, I'm trying to pad by 3, for base64 encoding.